# How can I use the equals() method in a JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, equals

In my JSP I need to test two objects using the `equals()` method.  Is there a way to do this using EL, JSTL, or another tag library? I am not allowed to use scriptlets due to team rules.

I tried to use the JSTL `<c:if>` tag, but it only seems to use the `==` operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JSP Expression Language operator `==` (or its alias, `eq`) performs comparison with the `equals` method, although some coercions are performed if one of the objects is a special type (BigDecimal, BigInteger, Double, Float, Long, Integer, Short, Byte, Character, Boolean, or String). You shouldn't need a tag for this, just `${a == b}`. If that doesn't fit in your context, could you please post more information?

Answer (score 0):

The [J2EE 1.4 guide](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) has an example of just that. You'll have to setup your once function lib, but it doesn't look hard.

Comment: A better link would be: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp77078